# JavaScript - DOM Manipulation - Trying to create an <li> element once a submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

As the title states, I am attempting to create what is essentially a to-do list. It isn’t going to be fancy until I learn more about js, so this is all I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Todo-List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h2>To-Do List</h2>
  </header>
  <form>
    <input id="textArea" type="text" placeholder="Enter list item here!"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="tasks-div">
  <ul id="tasks-list"></ul>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


let textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let li = document.createElement("li");

//add todos
submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
 let value = textArea.value;
 ul.appendChild(li);
 li.textContent = value; 
});
```

Ideally, I want the submit feature to take the value from the textArea, append the content of the textArea to the li element, and create a list. How can I get this working properly?

Comment: This is because you use a form. on each submit the browser re-load the entire page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea id="textArea">
  This text will be copied in a list item
</textarea>
<ul id="uoList">

</ul>
<button id="addToList">
   Add list item
</button>

<script>
    var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
    var addToList = document.getElementById("addToList");
    var uoList = document.getElementById("uoList");
    addToList.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = textArea.value;
        uoList.appendChild(li)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Actually the author's code does not have a problem when the `li` was added before its `innerText` is set. The variable for the `li` still holds the instance after appending it to the `ul` so setting the value after will still work. His problem is the behavior of the submit button itself and that the instance of the `li` is always the first instance since the `createElement` is not done on `click` callback.

Comment: Ah! Completely agree. Will edit my comment and remove the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `preventDefault()` method to stop the default behavior of a submit button refreshing the page. And instantiate the new `li` element in the closure of your callback function. Otherwise, it will just add for the first time and replace the existing with the new entered value.

```
<script>
    let textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
    let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

    //add todos
    submit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let value = textArea.value;
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = value;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
</script>
```